# Django Alternative To Inner Join When Annotating

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm having some trouble generating an annotation for the following models:

```
class ResultCode(GenericSteamDataModel):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='PID')
    result_code = models.IntegerField(db_column='resultcode', primary_key=True)
    campaign = models.OneToOneField(SteamCampaign, db_column='campagnePID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sale = models.BooleanField(db_column='ishit')
    factor = models.DecimalField(db_column='factor', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['result_code', 'campaign'],  name='result_code per campaign unique')
        ]

class CallStatistics(GenericShardedDataModel, GenericSteamDataModel):
    objects = CallStatisticsManager()
    project = models.OneToOneField(SteamProject, primary_key=True, db_column='projectpid', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result_code = models.ForeignKey(ResultCode, db_column='resultcode', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

**The goal** is to find the sum of *factor*s based on the *result_code* field in the ResultCode and CallStatistics model, when sale=True.

**Note that:**
Result codes are not unique by themselves (described in model). A Project has a relation to a Campaign

The following annotation generates the result that is desired (**possible solution**):

```
result = CallStatistics.objects.all().values('project').annotate(
sales_factored=models.Sum(
    models.Case(
        models.When(
            models.Q(sale=True) & models.Q(project__campaign=models.F('result_code__campaign')),
            then=models.F('result_code__factor')
        )
    )    
)
```

)

**The problem** is that the generated query performs a Inner Join on result_code between the 2 models.
Trying to add another field in the same annotation (that should not be joined with Resultcode), for example:

```
sales=models.Sum(Cast('sale', models.IntegerField())),
```

results in a wrong summation.

**The Questions** is if there is an alternative to the automatic Inner Join that Django generates. So that it is possible to retrieve the following fields (and others similar) in 1 annotation:

```
...
sales=models.Sum(Cast('sale', models.IntegerField())),
sales_factored= [sum of factores, without Inner Join]
...
```

Thanks in advance for taking your time for this.